# Combining two list variables into one operation

Tags: c#, linq

What I have that I start with is three string variables for example

```
string myVar1 = "hi";
string myVar2 = "bye";
string myVar3 = "who dis";
```

**CURRENTLY** I am doing this, It "works" but I feel like there is redundancy:

```
    List<string> listOne= new List<string>
    {
        myVar1 , myVar2,myVar3 
    };
    listOne= listOne.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)).Select(t => t).ToList();

    var whatIFinallyWantToHave= new HashSet<string>(listOne, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I am thinking there should be a way to get rid of listOne and do it in one go. Do you know how? ( note we still need to ignore the empty or null strings that listOne  is cleaning.)

Comment: @Rango thank you, how about ignoring the values that are null or empty ? before addign them to my hashset?

Comment: Note that `Select(t => t)` is only useful in rare cases (typically involving `GroupBy`), e.g. it does nothing but waste time here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth adding an extension in this case so you can chain from the list to the set directly. This way you don't have to break the flow to explicitly construct the hash set. Perhaps:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
string myVar1 = "hi";
string nully = null;
string myVar2 = "bye";
string empty = "";
string myVar3 = "who dis";
string dup = "WHO DIS";

List<string> listOne = new List<string>
{
    nully, myVar1, empty, myVar2 ,myVar3, dup
};

listOne
    .Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
    .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
// hi
// bye
// who dis
```

Comment: Note that `ToHashSet` is included in .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: In the fantastical lands of Java, it's rumored all you'd need is `new HashSet<String>(listOne);`

Comment: @SnakeDoc I don't see where the Java `HashSet` constructor doesn't allow storing `null` or empty strings?

Comment: @NetMage In Javaland, there's a saying that goes `If 't be true one wishes to preventeth st'rage of null, one shouldst useth TreeSet instead.` Of course, one could always follow the Javaland tenant Lists 'n Nulls: "`If 't be true one wishes to conv'rt a List into a HashSet, foregoing all null and empty strings, one shalt simply useth List.removeAll() bef'rehand`".

Comment: @SnakeDoc I assume `List.removeAll()` would modify the original list, which seems like unnecessary work compared to the filtering by LINQ, but also since it takes a `Collection<>` and not a predicate using the `Collection#removeIf()` would seem more appropriate, though still modifying the original `List`.

Comment: @NetMage T Shalt beest known HashSet implements the Set int'rface, which eke enwheels a removeAll() method as well!

Comment: @SnakeDoc But is there a `HashSet#removeIf`? (PS Still lacking compared to C# to remove (i.e. add object then remove object instead of add desired objects))

Comment: @SnakeDoc, I looked into doing this in a reasonable way in Java and found that Javaland is a horrible place to be.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils But Javaland has compile-time annotations! They're magical, powerful, and bring a warm smile of joy to any developer's face. It's been said, every time `@Nullable` is used, an angel get's her wings.

Comment: @SnakeDoc But C# has runtime user defined source attributes! And C# 8.0 will have non-nullable by default... which is actually enforced by the compiler and runtime :D

Comment: @NetMage Ah, so the proficy foretold! What is not h're the present day, is not h're anon. Javaland's enum types have been revered across the land for their immense power and and great fortitude. On occasion, the god's themselves have been known to seek a Javaland enum to fulfill a particularly treacherous quest of fortune and fame.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Hmmm... I see only a horrible kludge intent on avoiding the C-style enum that C# has as its enum base without adding any power and at space and time costs (though I guess that is never a Java concern...).

Comment: @NetMage "Beest not conc'rn'd with fartuous space constraints in the day of multiple-t'rabyte hard disks and ram wond'rfully abound and plentiful!" once exclaimed a Javaland fortune bearer. Javaland enums, containing both methods and attributes can smite even the mightiest of class type enemies, slay the ugliest of multi-threaded beasts, and lay waste to the most entrenched instance foes imaginable - and those even not!

Comment: @NetMage I shalt not defend any of Android's atrocities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to create a `List` or have a separate variable, but you have to combine the individual values somehow. Also, there is no reason to create (yet) another `List` just because you are filtering.

```
string myVar1 = "hi";
string myVar2 = "bye";
string myVar3 = "who dis";

var whatIFinallyWantToHave = new[] { myVar1, myVar2, myVar3 }
                             .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                             .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

NOTE: This requires .Net 4.7.2 for the `ToHashSet` method.